# Import external css in a Kotlin React app

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js, kotlin-frontend

I want to use css library like bootstrap/material inside my Kotlin-React app. Is there a way to import those external css libraries? There is a [Kotlin-Styled](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/tree/master/kotlin-styled) wrapper but not sure how to use it to import css.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this @Prabhakar? I am trying to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct answer how to import a piece of external CSS, but let me show you how I successfully used [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) library with Kotlin and React. Here's a demo of the project: https://krzema12.github.io/fsynth/

See an example Kotlin typing for a Material UI component:

```
@file:JsModule("@material-ui/core/ListItem")

package it.krzeminski.fsynth.typings.materialui.widgets

import react.RProps
import react.RState
import react.ReactElement

@JsName("default")
external class ListItem : react.Component<RProps, RState> {
    override fun render(): ReactElement?
}
```

(source: https://github.com/krzema12/fsynth/blob/master/web/src/main/kotlin/it/krzeminski/fsynth/typings/materialui/widgets/ListItem.kt)

and a convenience wrapper:

```
fun RBuilder.materialListItem(handler: RHandler<RProps>) = child(ListItem::class) {
    handler()
}
```

(source: https://github.com/krzema12/fsynth/blob/master/web/src/main/kotlin/it/krzeminski/fsynth/typings/MaterialUiBuilders.kt#L42)

Then I could use this component in the following way:

```
materialListItem {
...children...
}
```

(source: https://github.com/krzema12/fsynth/blob/master/web/src/main/kotlin/it/krzeminski/fsynth/App.kt)

From what I understand from [this docs page of Material UI](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/), it works and it's enough because CSS is embedded within JavaScript.

Comment: Any idea how to do this when the CSS is not included in the JS of the library you are importing?